# glXSwapIntervalSGI segfault

Tags: linux, opengl, segmentation-fault, sdl, vsync

I'm trying to disable vertical sync on Linux in a program built around SDL and openGL. I am running an old integrated ATI card with Gallium 0.4 as the driver.

I attempt to disable vsync by calling `glXSwapInterval(0)` in my code, but when I do this, although the program compiles fine, I get a segfault when I try to run it.

gdb gives me the rather unhelpful message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Does anyone have any idea as to what might be going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

glXSwapIntervalEXT and glXSwapIntervalSGI are extension functions; You normally access extensions' function addresses through glXGetProcAddress, though some libGL.so may export them directly.

Most easy solution: Get a OpenGL extension loader library, like GLEW (it's in all major Linux distribution's package repositories). Replace all occurances of `#include <GL/gl.h>` with `#include <GL/glew.h>` and `#include <GL/glx.h>` with `#include <GL/glxew.h>`, add libGLEW.so to your list of linked libraries, and call `glewInit()` right after creating and binding a OpenGL context. *Then test if the extension is actually available!*

Comment: Thanks - I was already using `gl/glxew.h` - I was just trying to call `glXSwapInterval` before `glewInit`! After moving the call everything works fine. (I'll accept the answer as soon as I can...)